# Execute Android deleteNotificationChannel for more than 5 channel_id

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-notifications

I have more than 10 notification channel , out of 10 i have to delete 5 channel in single button click event. So i got the channel id into string array and make it for loop and executed,

```
for (){
notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channel_id[i]);
}
```

But it's not working (Means it not deleting the notification channel). At the same time i have made it like

```
 for (){
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channel_id[i]);
    }
};

thread.start();
}
```

This time its deleting all 5 channels(Same thing while doing it in Async Task also). I have referred the android developer website, i didn't find anything related to **thread vs deleteNotificationChannel**.

Could any one have idea on this? Why its working in other worker thread but not in MainThread

Comment: Seems unlikely. Is it possible you are re-creating the missing channels, in a racy fashion, without realizing it? That is, could the threaded version be working because the `deleteNotificationChannel()` calls occur after a few μs delay?

Comment: Thanks a lot man. The same problem happened, we didn't noticed the notification creation part .